# Error in init.ts when using jsTreeR's grid parameter

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, htmlwidgets, jstreer

I've already raised the issue [here](https://github.com/stla/jsTreeR/issues/23) and [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3981). By now a [workaround exists](https://github.com/stla/jsTreeR/issues/23#issuecomment-1938935935) however, I still don't understand the root cause.

When running the following app using the latest CRAN version of `library(shiny)` and `library(jsTreeR)` (2.5.0) **after resizing the browser window** this error can be seen in the browser console:

[image]

**Example app:**

```
library(jsTreeR)
library(shiny)

nodes <- list(
  list(
    text = "Fruits",
    type = "fruit",
    children = list(
      list(
        text = "Apple",
        type = "fruit",
        data = list(
          quantity = 20
        )
      ),
      list(
        text = "Banana",
        type = "fruit",
        data = list(
          quantity = 31
        )
      ),
      list(
        text = "Grapes",
        type = "fruit",
        data = list(
          quantity = 34
        )
      )
    ),
    state = list(
      opened = TRUE
    )
  )
)

grid <- list(
  columns = list(
    list(
      width = 200,
      header = "Product"
    ),
    list(
      width = 150,
      value = "quantity",
      header = "Quantity"
    )
  )
)

ui <-   fluidPage(
  titlePanel("jsTree grid"),
  jstreeOutput("jstree")
)

server <-   function(input, output, session){
  output$jstree <- renderJstree(jstree(nodes, search = TRUE, grid = grid))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This is only the case when `jstree` is provided with the `grid` parameter.

@StéphaneLaurent [identified](https://github.com/stla/jsTreeR/issues/23#issuecomment-1938935935)  that the class `shiny-bound-output` is assigned to the `jstree-grid-wrapper` div which causes the issue and that removing it prevents the error.

I'd like to understand why this class is added in the first place and if there is a proper way to implement the `grid` parameter without running into this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is in the file [jstreegrid.js](https://github.com/deitch/jstree-grid/blob/master/jstreegrid.js), in the listener of the `ready.jstree` event, code starting at line 493:

```js
.on(
  "ready.jstree",
  $.proxy(function (e, data) {
    // find the line-height of the first known node
    var anchorHeight = this.element
        .find("[class~='jstree-anchor']:first")
        .outerHeight(),
      q,
      cls = this.element.attr("class") || "";
    $(
      '<style type="text/css">div.jstree-grid-cell-root-' +
        this.rootid +
        " {line-height: " +
        anchorHeight +
        "px; height: " +
        anchorHeight +
        "px;}</style>"
    ).appendTo("head");

    // add container classes to the wrapper - EXCEPT those that are added by jstree, i.e. "jstree" and "jstree-*"
    q = cls.split(/\s+/).map(function (i) {
      var match = i.match(/^jstree(-|$)/);
      return match ? "" : i;
    });
    this.gridWrapper.addClass(q.join(" "));
  }, this)
);
```

In this code, `cls = this.element.attr("class")` is the character string made of all classes attributed to the tree, separated by a white space. Then `q = cls.split(/\s+/).map(...` is the array of all these classes except the `jstree` class and the classes started with `jstree-`, and these classes are then added to the grid (the `jstree-grid-wrapper` div). And then I see two possibilities:

- at this stage, the tree already has the `shiny-bound-output` class, which is then added to the grid;
- or the tree does not have the `shiny-bound-output` class yet, but it has the class `jstreer`, and then **htmlwidgets** adds the class `shiny-bound-output` to all elements having the `jstreer` class.

---

## Edit

I've just checked, and the tree has both classes `shiny-bound-output` and `jstreer` at this stage.

A possible solution is to modify **jstreegrid.js** so that it does not copy these classes to the grid. In fact I don't see any other solution.